# Programatically make TextView background color change while pressed

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some TextViews which are dinamically added to a LinearLayout. These TextViews are clickable and have an onLongClickListener (I also intend to add onClickListener later)

Here is the thing, I want these TextView to change their background color when pressed and I read that you can use selectors to do such thing.

So I made this xml file in res/drawable/text_view_pressed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="#000000"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</selector>
```

I tried to create a TextView and using this xml file likes this:

```
TextView t = new TextView(this);
t.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.text_view_pressed);
```

But when I do this, it will give this error in t.setBackgroundColor: "Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here: getResources().getColor(R.color.text_view_pressed)" but it doesn't work as intended if I use getResources().getColor(R.color.text_view_pressed).

Anyone got an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. However there is an important detail.

There are two types of resources that can be affected by states: [`ColorStateList`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) and [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

A color state list can only be used in certain contexts, for example in [`TextView.setTextColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28android.content.res.ColorStateList%29). As far as I can see, you cannot use a color state list as parameter of `setBackgroundColor()` if you want to change the background of a View when it's pressed. You need a state list drawable for that. And in a state list drawable, the `android:drawable` attribute is mandatory.

So, to sum up:

- The xml file should be placed in `res\drawable`,
- Its structure should be slightly different (i.e. state list, not color list), and
- You need to use  `setBackgroundResource()` instead of `setBackgroundColor()`.

Example file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

If you want to use custom colors instead of white and black, you simply need to [define them as resources in `res\values`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color) and reference them from here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did what you said but the app just stops with a fatal exeception now.

07-06 23:18:21.330: E/AndroidRuntime(4480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.rodrigo.davy.vazdividiraconta/br.rodrigo.davy.vazdividiraconta.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/text_view_pressed.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020058

Comment: @Rodrigo yes, a corollary is that the file should go in res\drawable. Sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: Thanks for your good will! I had already changed the folder to res\drawable when you mentioned that "A selector is a StateListDrawable, a type of drawable" before. It still gives me the same error, though.

Comment: @Rodrigo Huh? Strange. Did you try refreshing and cleaning the project?

Comment: Just tried to refresh and clean. I even tried running the app in both my phone and my tablet. The results are always the same...

Comment: It is working now! Thank you for your time and collaboration!