# How to change TextView background color while it's pressed down?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

I try to change background of TextView1 while it's pressed down. This is my text.xml in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

And this is my Kotlin file:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app)

        var textview1 = findViewById(R.id.TextView1) as TextView

        textview1.setOnClickListener{
            val t = TextView(this)
            t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text)
        }
    }
```

I did this according to this answered answer: [Programatically make TextView background color change while pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602190/programatically-make-textview-background-color-change-while-pressed)

TextView1:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

Does anybody know what I'm missing? I'm begginer.

---

Sorry, it was my mistake in code. The correct code is:

```
 var textview1 = findViewById(R.id.TextView1) as TextView

        textview1.setOnClickListener {
            //val t = TextView(this)
            textview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text)
```

Comment: Set ontouchlistener if drawale file don't work and set event of touch down and touch up to set different color

Comment: Usually in a read only view there isn't a pressed state. Are you sure that you are looking for a textview? Why not a text button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the background on the textview before the onClick event and not after it. Right now, the color gets applied on a new Textview (`t`) after the click event has been processed. That Textview is not the view that was rendered on the screen (`textview1`)

Use one of the following:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text"/>
```

or

```
textview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text)
textview1.setOnClickListener{
             //Handle click
        }
```

Also, if you changed your code to:

```
textview1.setOnClickListener{
            textview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text)
        }
```

You'll notice that the state list does get applied **after** the first click

Answer (score 0):

**Use only if you want to ripple effect for click animation**

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although as stated above you can do this programmatically, the correct and easy way to do this is to go to your `styles` file and add a customized style for your TextView, in the style you can add colors based on different states and control everything the `TextView` has to offer, and then just go to your `.xml` file and add the style attribute and load up the style you had just created, it's easy and can be re-used on your entire app instead of copy pasting all that code for each time you need to do something like this.

Answer (score -1):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_training)

        var textview1 = findViewById(R.id.TextView1) as TextView

        textview1.setOnClickListener{
            val t = TextView(this)
            t.setBackground(R.drawable.text)
        }
    }
```